# IntelliSense suggestions for F# in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, f#, intellisense

In Visual C# 2010 Express, if I type `using S` suggestions automatically popup:

[image]

In Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web using F#, if I type 'open S' nothing happens. I have to key `ctrl-j` in order to trigger suggestions:

[image]

Is there any way to get the former behavior in 2012? I.e. not have to type `ctrj-j` for suggestions, but have them come up automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C# and F# Intellisense implementations are written by different teams and have different goals.  In general the F# experience is more minimal than the C# one.  For items like `open` they won't automatically popup an experience and you must manually invoke it.  There is no way to change this behavior.